# How do I fix this JSON parsing issue?

Tags: html, json, parsing, fetch, body-parser

I send data with `fetch()` in HTML to an express API, this is how it comes out in the `req.body` (I use body-parser)

```
{
  '{"address":"a","town":"NYC","details":"a","appr":': { '"Car1"': '' }
}
```

it's all "stringy", as the only way I know to "parse it" to send it, is to send it with JSON.stringify. But, upon getting the info, it's "unparseable", JSON.parse errors with `"unexpected string in JSON at position 62"`

I send it like:

```
    body: JSON.stringify({
      address: address,
      town: town,
      details: details,
      appr: apr,
    }),
```

I've tried everything I know how to do to attempt to "make it a JSON" again, but nothing has worked.

Comment: The return value is not valid json. You can check it here: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: looks like you have a typo in appr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Don't forget to add header to fetch

```
 const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json' // => this is important
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
```

2 - Don't forget to add this on express

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

**Note:** If you are using Express v4.16.0 or newer you can use built-in middleware. Thanks to [@Dov Rine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5277922/dov-rine)

```
app.use(express.json());
```

3 - req.body will be available as object after this. You should not use JSON.parse(req.body) because body-parser does this for you.

```
let address = req.body.address;
```

Comment: bodyParser is merged into the newer versions of express, so app.use(express.json());

Comment: Thank you, which version specifically (for edit)?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: "This middleware is available in Express v4.16.0 onwards."

Comment: I think that his issue is on the frontend, though. It looks like he's sending malformed json

Comment: There is no way to output malformed JSON from JSON.stringify() i think. This should be content type problem.

Comment: Actually, that sounds right. The JSON that OP posted at the top is definitely not valid, so I just assumed that it came in bad from his frontend. His stringify statement almost certainly has a typo, too. I think that's what threw me.

Comment: Final thought, I think Bee is parsing already parsed object. That's why JSON.parse does not work.

Comment: So, he's effectively calling JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(data)). That could explain all of it. It's a frontend problem that's hard to find and shows up on the backend like he posted.

Comment: Comes out like this if doubled: "{\"address\":\"a\",\"town\":\"NYC\",\"details\":\"a\",\"appr\":{\"Car1\":\"\"}}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238350/discussion-between-can-ozgen-and-dov-rine).